# Gensim Keywords, how to load a german model?

Tags: nlp, keyword, gensim, word2vec

I'm try to get started with the gensim library. My goal is pretty simple. I want to use the keywords extraction provided by gensim on a german text. Unfortunately, i'm failing hard.

Gensim comes with a keywords extraction build in, it is build on TextRank. While the results look good on english text, it seems not to work on german. I simple installed gensim via pypi and used it out of the box. Well such AI Products are usually driven by a model. My guess is that gensim comes with a english model. A word2vec model for german is available on a [github page](https://github.com/devmount/GermanWordEmbeddings).

But here i'm stuck, i can't find a way how the summarization module of gensim, which provides the [keywords function](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/summarization/keywords.html) i'm looking for, can work with a external model.

So the basic question is, how do i load the german model and get keywords from german text?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in the `gensim` docs, or the [original TextRank paper](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~mihalcea/papers/mihalcea.emnlp04.pdf) (from 2004), suggesting that algorithm requires a Word2Vec model as input. (Word2Vec was 1st published around 2013.) It just takes word-tokens.

See examples of its use in the tutorial notebook that's included with `gensim`:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/summarization_tutorial.ipynb

I'm not sure the same algorithm would work as well on German text, given the differing importance of compound words. (To my eyes, TextRank isn't very impressive with English, either.) You'd have to check the literature to see if it still gives respected results. (Perhaps some sort of extra stemming/intraword-tokenizing/canonicalization would help.)